# How to cleanly remove Exim4 mail server on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, exim, exim4

After successfully using Postfix on my Ubuntu machines, I decided to try Exim on a new server, based on some people commenting it's easier to set up and use.

Well I ran into issues with my Rails app right away, and, considering how easy Postfix had been to use, I decided to remove Exim and install Postfix instead.

However, how to cleanly remove it was hard to find...

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Here's all you need to do to cleanly and easily get rid of Exim4:

```
apt-get remove exim4 exim4-base exim4-config exim4-daemon-light
```

You may have the exim4 logs directory left behind. Just get rid of it manually, if you do:

```
rm -r /var/log/exim4/
```

Comment: apt-get --purge remove if you want to remove the configuration files as well.

Comment: `rm -r /var/spool/exim4/` ?? <- attention to the interrogant marks, I removed this folder but don't know if it is recommendable

Comment: `rm /etc/init.d/exim4` ??

Comment: Note that order is very important here. If you merely disable exim, install another MTA, then remove exim4... the removal deletes the sendmail link created by your active MTA.

Comment: @user890155 What is an MTA?

Answer (score 1):

What I would do:

```
apt-get remove exim4*
```